# df.hist() vs. df.plot.hist()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Sorry if my question seems basic, but I couldn't find a straight answer. Currently learning about pandas visualization and didn't understand the difference between `df.hist()` vs. `df.plot.hist()` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-hist), respectively). Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: There is no difference in functionality. `df.plot.hist()` is more consistent with other plotting syntax like `df.plot.bar()` or `df.plot.scatter()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest There has to be a difference ,because `df.plot.hist()` is my case it says "lengths must match to compare", and `df.hist` happily prints a bunch of plots. Now if I could only combine them into one stacked plot while passing "by=" to it..

Answer (score 8):

They do different things, `df.hist()` will produce a separate plot for each `Series` whilst `df.plot.hist()` will produce a stacked single plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
...     'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1]
...     }, index= ['pig', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'chicken', 'horse'])
df.hist(bins=3)
```

produces:

[image]

Whilst `df.plot.hist(bins=3)` produces:

[image]

So it's down to what you want, they are convenience functions for different uses.